# Adding custom attribute programatically no entry in eav_attribute table

Tags: magento2

**\Custom\Attribute\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Custom_Attribute" setup_version="2.2.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
</config>
```

**\Custom\Attribute\registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Custom_Attribute',
__DIR__
);
```

**Custom\Attribute\Setup\InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Attribute\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
private $eavSetupFactory;

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'sample_attribute',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Sample Atrribute',
            'input' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
     );
  }
}
```

Cleared var/gen

Ran setup upgrade.

No logs.

No entry in eav_attribute.

Comment: InstallData class is only loaded if no record of your module exists in the setup_module table. If a record does exist but has an older version number than declared in module.xml Magento will look for an UpgradeData class which must implement UpgradeDataInterface

Comment: Yes in my custom module, there are no records but still no entry in eav

Comment: May be this link will help you. https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-attribute-programatically-magento2/

Comment: I have followed the same link

Comment: when you run setup:upgrade do you see your module in the list of processed modules?

Comment: yes new module listed, and no exceptions

Comment: ok got it...i had to uninstall the module and run upgrade cmd

Comment: But how to add multiple attributes